# Android Qt application with GStreamer crashes on startup

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm trying to integrate GStreamer into a Qt based Android application, but it always crashes on startup.  The smallest program that does anything related to GStreamer crashes.  Here's a minimal example:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int ret;
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  gst_is_initialized ();

  return app.exec();
```

When running in the debugger, the following stacktrace is what appears:

[image: stacktrace]

This happens as long as there is some code that references functions within gstreamer, even if that code is never called.  The following output is printed out:

```
I le.QtGstAndroi: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
I le.QtGstAndroi: Bumping SignalCatcher priority from 5 to 10
W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
W le.QtGstAndroi: Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;->getDisplay()Landroid/view/Display; (light greylist, linking)
D OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
I QtCore  : Start
I Qt      : qt started
F libc    : Fatal signal 31 (SIGSYS), code 1 (SYS_SECCOMP) in tid 20703 (qtMainLoopThrea), pid 20668 (le.QtGstAndroid)
```

I have two ideas as to what it could be:

1. Permissions issue(as the `SYS_SECCOMP` would imply).  I don't know what permission this would be complaining about, as the code within glib seems to just be calling `pthread_cond_broadcast`
2. Some sort of threading issue, since this crash appears to be happening well before `main()` is even called and I'm not sure if things are trying to be initialized in a thread that is not the main thread.

Is there something else that could be going wrong with the initialization sequence?

Comment: Are you sure that stack trace is for thread 20703?

Comment: Yes, it always happens in the thread named `qtMainLoopThre`.